# XPath not found by Selenium but works with jQuery

Tags: selenium, xpath

Given that I have the following XPath:

```
//table[@title="someTitle"]//td[@id="someId"][3]
```

When I try to click on this element using WebDriver's element(By.xpath(someXpathString)).click(); I get the "ElementNotFound" exception.

However, when I try finding the element using the SAME XPath but using the console in Chrome DevTools it returns exactly the element that I'm looking for. The call looks like this:

```
$x('//table[@title="someTitle"]//td[@id="someId"][3]');
```

Now, I know that if I use THIS XPath:

```
(//table[@title="someTitle"]//td[@id="someId"])[3]
```

in WebDriver, the element is found and click works.

- **Please note** that I want to be able to find the 2nd, 3rd or even 4th element by that selector. This is a workaround for interacting with table cells on the same column but different rows.

My question is: why does the Chrome console recognize the element using the XPath **without parenthesis** while the Find function does not, and what is the actual difference between the two XPaths?

I've noticed on other elements that the parenthesis notation is NOT needed in order to select the 2nd or higher element of that type, so I would like a clear explanation on how this type of XPath works, what is the logic behind it.

Comment: Can you share the selenium and jquery code snippets? Are you sure there are no typos?

Comment: I can't really share the actual code (company policy) but yes, I'm sure there are no typos. The exact same XPath with parenthesis works, without parenthesis it gives element not found exception. And indeed, I've tested on Chrome with DevTools, and the same thing happens, element is not selected without using the parenthesis before the element number.

Comment: `$x` is not jQuery, it's your browser's built-in utility for evaluating xpath

Comment: @derloopkat ok, but it's the same XPath expression and that still doesn't explain why the parenthesis is required. I've tested this on both FireFox and Chrome. It would make sense that both Find and $x would evaluate the expression in the same way, since they both work on Chrome.

Comment: @SorinD., then edit your question. jQuery selectors are Sizzle, not XPath. You're using your console for evaluating those XPaths, not jQuery.

Comment: @derloopkat Done. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both xpaths are different.

1. `//table[@title="someTitle"]//td[@id="someId"][3]` -- will select only 3 column elements
2. `(//table[@title="someTitle"]//td[@id="someId"])[3]` -- selects all columns and then returns only one element indexed at 3.

For example assume a table with 4 rows and 4 columns.
First xpath selects only elements in the third column of each row (total 4).
But second xpath slect only one element, ie column number 3 at row 1, irrespective of number rows in the table.

if we use find element, both will return only one element. But if we use find elements, first will return  4 elements but second xpath returns only one element.

Comment: That makes sense now, thank you! I made a confusion when I tried searching with [1] and it worked in both cases so I couldn't get my head around the reason why.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to the page where your element is from another page, try refreshing -

```
driver.navigate().refresh();
```